# AIR - StageWebView issue on iPhone when typing into a text field

Tags: iphone, ios, air, textfield

I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 to build an iPhone app with AIR 3.

I am implementing the FacebookMobile flash API which uses a StageWebView to display the login form. Everything works fine when I test my app locally (on my computer) but the app always crashes on iPhone as soon as I click on the "Email" text field to type my email and be able to login. The iPhone's keyboard is shown and then my app simply freeze forever (I don't have time to write any character in the text field).

Am I doing something wrong with my StageWebView? I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
public var webView:StageWebView;
```

Here is the code where I initialize the StageWebView :

```
webView = new StageWebView();
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
FacebookMobile.login(handleLogin, stage, permissions, webView);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem too.

When editing a text field, the keyboard appears, but it freezes straight.

Note: when I used CS5 away back it never happend.

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(10 , 64, 300, 400 );
webView.loadURL( "http://ghasan.yoo7.com/h54-page" );
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeWebView);

function closeWebView(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    webView.stage = null;
    webView.dispose();
}
```